# ExcelDNA: commands with parameters , return data types

Tags: c#, sql, excel, vba

Apologies if you have seen something like this before, I have scoured the forums as best I can.  I am trying to get a definitive answer to a question that I think I have seen answered on a different forum - I am just very much hoping I misunderstood the answer.

In summary, I want to write vba subs / functions that take parameters and retrieve data from a SQL database via a C# business logic layer and ExcelDNA.

The C# layer is part of a .Net solution that marshalls requests from multiple applications to multiple databases. Config is managed centrally and DataAccess objects are created at runtime in a factory.

Return types can vary depending on requesting app - the same data might be requested as a Dictionary, DataTable etc.  Depending on user permission/access, input params etc, the business layer will perform various aggregation and calculation actions on the data before returning objects to the requesting apps.

Unfortunately, one user has an application based in Excel that I now must integrate.  From reading about VSTO, COM, Automation Add-in and ExcelDNA, I decided it would be best to add a project to the solution that interfaces with ExcelDNA. But after a lot of baby steps to return simple strings from SQL to Excel functions in cells, I now need to try and return a DataTable (flexible here) to a VBA function.  The VBA would take in some parameters, such as Database name, environment (PROD, UAT, DEV), ModelRunId, startDate, endDate....

But from what I have read, this is not possible.  Has anyone achieved this?  I am this close to writing a simple WinForms app and exposing the "Export to Excel" functionality on some grids - let the Excel user do the leg work....

Writing to SQL server direct and using methods like CopyFromRecordSet is not an option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The objective of ExcelDNA is to make it efficient and simple to create .NET UDFs - why do you need to create VBA UDFs?

Comment: If your problem is how to make an Excel UDF return a table of values to multiple cells look at creating an array UDF.

Comment: I don't want a UDF in VBA.  All of the functionality is in the C# layer.  It does the data retrieval, aggregation, calculated fields, drops data based on security rules etc.  I just want to be able to call these C# functions from VBA.  The call will have to include some parameters. The size of the returned table could be variable in terms of columns and rows so I thought this could make life difficult with arrays in vba.  Perhaps I could return DOM documents?

Comment: Which part of your plan is giving you a problem?It sounds like you could make a macro in Excel-DNA that retrieves and examines the DataTable and places that data into a sheet. If you need to show the user some UI to select what data, you could create that as a Ribbon tab or as a Windows Forms GUI.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for responding to this.  I read that you cannot pass parameters to [ExcelCommand()] in ExcelDNA and I would need to, in order to specify what is returned. Regards, James

Comment: The latest Excel-DNA check-in on CodePlex now supports macros with parameters. See http://exceldna.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to create a COM server in C# / .NET and expose this to Excel VBA.

As an example, create a class in C#, make it COM visible and give it a GUID and a ProgId, like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("AAA82C86-91CF-496C-A8BA-70742DC58475")]
[ProgId("MyVbaFunctions")]
public class MyVbaFunctions
{
    public string GetSomeData(string arg1)
    {
        return "Return your data";
    }
}
```

You then need to tick the "Register for COM Interop" option in the Build preferences in Visual Studio. Once you have built your project, you can go into the Excel VBA editor, click on the Tools --> References menu, find your assembly in the list of registered type libraries and tick it.

You then should be able to write a VBA macro that uses your C# classes. Something like this in VBA:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Dim MyFuncs As New MyLibrary.MyVbaFunctions
    Debug.Print MyFuncs.GetSomeData("hello")
End Sub
```

Obviously you can extend your library to contain several classes and methods, all backed by C#.

When it comes to deploying your assembly to users, you need to register it using "regasm.exe /codebase MyLibrary.dll" (use '/u' to unregister it).

Since you are already using Excel-DNA, you should take a look at the trunk source code which has some support for an [ExcelComClass] attribute which lets Excel-DNA host your COM server rather than the default (mscoree.dll). This means your functions will run in the same app domain as your UDFs.